# updated utility for automatic websocket ping-pong and receiving round-trip time reports

Tags: java, websocket

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/289045/249240). Please check it out first for the motivations, known use-cases and explanations.

In this new version I've applied several of advices from [this answer by @J_H](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/289049/249240):

- instead of a random ping content, timestamp and sequence number with hash "signature" are sent. This allows to report accurate RTT even for timed-out pongs when they finally arrive (instead of `-1`) and detect totally messed-up peers that reply to pings not in order.
- to address the issue of network activity spikes, each connection pinging is scheduled in a separate task as connections arrive, so pinging of all connections should naturally get distributed equally across the interval. However just in case, it is now also possible to provide a custom [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) via a constructor param, so things like [JitterScheduledThreadPoolExecutorImpl](https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/JitterScheduledThreadPoolExecutorImpl.html) can be used if needed.
- some old, unused constructor variants were removed (they were kept for backward-compatibility with an older version that allowed to specify interval only in seconds, but it was a high time get rid of them). In constructors for `expect-timely-pongs` mode non-negative `failureLimit` is enforced.

The below new version is available on github at [cr-stackexchange-2 tag](https://github.com/morgwai/servlet-utils/blob/cr-stackexchange-2/src/main/java/pl/morgwai/base/servlet/utils/WebsocketPingerService.java).

Currently, developers using it in the following 3 use-cases LGTM-ed it after a **preliminary** testing:

- standard web app servers using `expect-timely-pongs` mode with intervals of about `55s` and failure limit of `0` or `1` (dozens of apps by several parties, dozens of thousands of end users, up to medium qps in most apps).
- desktop user-agent clients using `keep-alive-only` mode with intervals of about `10s` - `30s` (2 apps by 1 party, few dozens of end users).
- real-time online game servers using `expect-timely-pongs` mode with intervals of about `500ms` and RTT reporting (1 app, undisclosed amount of end users, high qps)

Still, if someone has another perspective/use-case, more feedback would be most valuable.
Furthermore, as mentioned, this version received only some preliminary testing so far, so it's quite possible, that it may contain some bugs...

```java
// Copyright 2021 Piotr Morgwai Kotarbinski, Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0
package pl.morgwai.base.servlet.utils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.*;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.websocket.*;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason.CloseCodes;
import javax.websocket.RemoteEndpoint.Async;

import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;



/**
 * Automatically pings and handles pongs from websocket {@link Session connections}.
 * Depending on constructor used, operates in either
 * {@link #WebsocketPingerService(long, TimeUnit, int, String, ScheduledExecutorService, boolean)
 * expect-timely-pongs mode} or
 * {@link #WebsocketPingerService(long, TimeUnit, String, ScheduledExecutorService, boolean)
 * keep-alive-only mode}. The service can be used both on the client and the server side.
 * <p>
 * Instances are usually created at app startups and stored in locations easily reachable for
 * {@code Endpoint} instances or a code that manages them (for example as a
 * {@code ServletContext} attribute, a field in a class that creates client
 * {@link Session connections} or on some static var).<br/>
 * At app shutdowns, {@link #stop()} should be called to terminate the pinging
 * {@link ScheduledExecutorService scheduler}.</p>
 * <p>
 * Connections can be registered for pinging using {@link #addConnection(Session)}
 * and deregister using {@link #removeConnection(Session)}.</p>
 * <p>
 * If round-trip time discovery is needed, {@link #addConnection(Session, BiConsumer)} variant may
 * be used to receive RTT reports on each matching pong.</p>
 */
public class WebsocketPingerService {



    // design decision note: while it is possible to use unsolicited pongs for keep-alive-only,
    // some ping-pong implementations confuse them with malformed pongs and close connections.
    // Furthermore, using ping-pong allows to provide RTT reports in keep-alive-only mode also.



    /** The maximum length of ping data in bytes as per websocket spec. */
    public static final int MAX_PING_DATA_BYTES = 125;

    /** 55s as majority of proxies and NAT routers have a timeout of at least 60s. */
    public static final int DEFAULT_INTERVAL_SECONDS = 55;
    final long intervalNanos;

    /** Default {@link MessageDigest} for hashing ping content. */
    public static final String DEFAULT_HASH_FUNCTION = "SHA3-256";
    final String hashFunction;

    final int failureLimit;  // negative value means keep-alive-only mode
    final boolean synchronizeSending;
    final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    /** Periodic on {@link #scheduler}, executes {@link PingPongPlayer#sendPing()}. */
    final ConcurrentMap<Session, ScheduledFuture<?>> connectionPingingTasks =
            new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    final ConcurrentMap<Session, PingPongPlayer> connectionPingPongPlayers =
            new ConcurrentHashMap<>();



    /**
     * Constructs a new service in {@code expect-timely-pongs} mode.
     * Each timeout adds to a given {@link Session connection}'s failure count, unmatched pongs are
     * ignored, matching pongs received in a nonconsecutive order cause the connection to be closed
     * immediately with {@link CloseCodes#PROTOCOL_ERROR}.
     * @param interval interval between pings and also timeout for pongs. While this class does not
     *     enforce any hard limits, as of typical network and CPU capabilities of 2024, values below
     *     100ms are probably not a good idea in most cases and anything below 20ms is pure Sparta.
     * @param unit unit for {@code interval}.
     * @param failureLimit limit of timed-out pongs: if exceeded, then the given
     *     {@link Session connection} is closed with {@link CloseCodes#PROTOCOL_ERROR}. Each
     *     matching, timely pong resets the {@link Session connection}'s failure counter.
     * @param hashFunction name of a {@link MessageDigest} to use for ping content hashing. This
     *     must be supported by a registered {@link java.security.Provider security Provider} and
     *     {@link MessageDigest#getDigestLength() the length of produced hashes} must not exceed
     *     <code>({@value #MAX_PING_DATA_BYTES}-(2*{@value Long#BYTES}))</code> bytes, otherwise
     *     an {@link IllegalArgumentException} will be thrown.
     * @param scheduler used for scheduling pings. Upon a call to {@link #stop(long, TimeUnit)},
     *     {@code scheduler} will be {@link ScheduledExecutorService#shutdown() shutdown}.
     * @param synchronizeSending whether to synchronize ping sending on a given
     *     {@link Session connection}. Whether it is necessary depends on the container
     *     implementation being used. For example it is not necessary on Jetty, but it is on Tomcat:
     *     see <a href="https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56026">this bug report</a>.
     *     <br/>
     *     When using containers that do require such synchronization, all other message sending by
     *     {@code Endpoint}s must also be synchronized on the respective {@link Session connections}
     *     (please don't shoot the messenger...).
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code failureLimit} is negative or if
     *     {@code hashFunction} is not supported or produces too long hashes.
     */
    public WebsocketPingerService(
        long interval,
        TimeUnit unit,
        int failureLimit,
        String hashFunction,
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler,
        boolean synchronizeSending
    ) {
        this(
            interval,
            unit,
            failureLimit,
            hashFunction,
            scheduler,
            synchronizeSending,
            true
        );
    }

    /**
     * Calls {@link #WebsocketPingerService(long, TimeUnit, int, String, ScheduledExecutorService,
     * boolean) WebsocketPingerService} <code>(interval, unit, failureLimit,
     * {@value #DEFAULT_HASH_FUNCTION}, {@link #newDefaultScheduler()}, false)</code>
     * ({@code expect-timely-pongs} mode).
     */
    public WebsocketPingerService(long interval, TimeUnit unit, int failureLimit) {
        this(
            interval,
            unit,
            failureLimit,
            DEFAULT_HASH_FUNCTION,
            newDefaultScheduler(),
            false
        );
    }

    // design decision note: using interval as a timeout simplifies things A LOT. Using a separate
    // SHORTER duration for a timeout is still pretty feasible and may be implemented if there's
    // enough need for it. Allowing a timeouts longer than intervals OTOH would require scheduling
    // of on-timeout actions and is almost certainly not worth the effort.



    /**
     * Constructs a new service in {@code keep-alive-only} mode.
     * The service will not actively close any {@link Session connection} unless an
     * {@link IOException} occurs. The params have the similar meaning as in {@link
     * #WebsocketPingerService(long, TimeUnit, int, String, ScheduledExecutorService, boolean)}.
     */
    public WebsocketPingerService(
        long interval,
        TimeUnit unit,
        String hashFunction,
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler,
        boolean synchronizeSending
    ) {
        this(interval, unit, -1, hashFunction, scheduler, synchronizeSending, false);
    }

    /**
     * Calls
     * {@link #WebsocketPingerService(long, TimeUnit, String, ScheduledExecutorService, boolean)
     * WebsocketPingerService}<code>(interval, unit, {@value #DEFAULT_HASH_FUNCTION},
     * {@link #newDefaultScheduler()}, false)</code> ({@code keep-alive-only} mode).
     */
    public WebsocketPingerService(long interval, TimeUnit unit) {
        this(interval, unit, DEFAULT_HASH_FUNCTION, newDefaultScheduler(), false);
    }

    /**
     * Calls
     * {@link #WebsocketPingerService(long, TimeUnit, String, ScheduledExecutorService, boolean)
     * WebsocketPingerService}<code>({@link #DEFAULT_INTERVAL_SECONDS}, SECONDS,
     * {@value #DEFAULT_HASH_FUNCTION}, {@link #newDefaultScheduler()}, false)</code>
     * ({@code keep-alive-only} mode).
     */
    public WebsocketPingerService() {
        this(
            DEFAULT_INTERVAL_SECONDS,
            SECONDS,
            DEFAULT_HASH_FUNCTION,
            newDefaultScheduler(),
            false
        );
    }



    WebsocketPingerService(
        long interval,
        TimeUnit unit,
        int failureLimit,
        String hashFunction,
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler,
        boolean synchronizeSending,
        boolean expectTimelyPongsMode
    ) {
        if (expectTimelyPongsMode && failureLimit < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("failureLimit < 0");
        }
        this.intervalNanos = unit.toNanos(interval);
        this.failureLimit = failureLimit;
        this.synchronizeSending = synchronizeSending;
        this.hashFunction = hashFunction;
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
        final MessageDigest testInstance;
        try {
            testInstance = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashFunction);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
        if (testInstance.getDigestLength() > MAX_PING_DATA_BYTES - (2 * Long.BYTES)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(hashFunction + " produces too long hashes");
        }
    }



    /**
     * Registers {@code connection} for pinging.
     * Usually called in
     * {@link javax.websocket.Endpoint#onOpen(Session, javax.websocket.EndpointConfig) onOpen(...)}.
     */
    public void addConnection(Session connection) {
        addConnection(connection, null);
    }

    /**
     * Registers {@code connection} for pinging and receiving round-trip time reports via
     * {@code rttObserver}.
     * Usually called in
     * {@link javax.websocket.Endpoint#onOpen(Session, javax.websocket.EndpointConfig) onOpen(...)}.
     * <p>
     * Upon receiving a pong matching some ping previously sent to {@code connection},
     * {@code rttObserver} will be invoked with the round-trip time in nanoseconds as the second
     * argument and {@code  connection} as the first.</p>
     * <p>
     * Note that if the other side does not reply with pongs at all, {@code rttObserver} will not
     * be called at all either. If RTT report receiving is critical for a given app,
     * {@code expect-timely-pongs} mode should be used to disconnect misbehaving peers.</p>
     * <p>
     * {@code rttObserver} will be called by a container {@code Thread} bound by the websocket
     * {@code Endpoint} concurrency contract. Thus as with normal websocket event handling, it
     * should not be performing any long-running operations to not delay processing of subsequent
     * events. Particularly, if {@code rttObserver} processing or processing of any other event
     * blocks arrival of a pong, the corresponding RTT report will be inaccurate.</p>
     */
    public void addConnection(Session connection, BiConsumer<Session, Long> rttObserver) {
        final var pingPongPlayer = new PingPongPlayer(
            connection,
            intervalNanos,
            failureLimit,
            synchronizeSending,
            rttObserver,
            hashFunction
        );
        connectionPingPongPlayers.put(connection, pingPongPlayer);
        connectionPingingTasks.put(
            connection,
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(pingPongPlayer::sendPing, 0L, intervalNanos, NANOSECONDS)
        );
    }

    // design decision note: it seems that in vast majority of cases it is most conveniently for
    // developers if a receiver of RTT reports is the Endpoint instance associated with the
    // connection which reports concern. Container Threads calling Endpoints are bound by a
    // concurrency contract requiring that each Endpoint instance is called by at most 1 Thread at a
    // time. Therefore it would create a lot of problems for developers if delivering  of RTT
    // reports didn't adhere to this contract either.



    /**
     * Deregisters {@code connection} from this service, so it will not be pinged anymore.
     * Usually called in
     * {@link javax.websocket.Endpoint#onClose(Session, CloseReason) onClose(...)}.
     * @return {@code true} if {@code connection} had been {@link #addConnection(Session) added} to
     *     this service before and has been successfully removed by this method, {@code false} if it
     *     had not been added and no action has taken place.
     */
    public boolean removeConnection(Session connection) {
        final var pingingTask = connectionPingingTasks.remove(connection);
        if (pingingTask == null) return false;
        pingingTask.cancel(false);
        connectionPingPongPlayers.remove(connection);
        return true;
    }



    /** Whether {@code connection} is {@link #addConnection(Session) registered} in this service. */
    public boolean containsConnection(Session connection) {
        return connectionPingPongPlayers.containsKey(connection);
    }



    /** The number of currently registered {@link Session connections}. */
    public int getNumberOfConnections() {
        return connectionPingPongPlayers.size();
    }



    /**
     * Stops the service and {@link ScheduledExecutorService#shutdown() shutdowns} its scheduler.
     * After a call to this method the service becomes no longer usable and should be discarded.
     * @return {@link Session connections} that were still registered at the time this method was
     * called.
     */
    public Set<Session> stop(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) {
        scheduler.shutdown();
        for (var pingPongPlayer: connectionPingPongPlayers.values()) pingPongPlayer.deregister();
        try {
            scheduler.awaitTermination(timeout, unit);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
        if ( !scheduler.isTerminated()) {  // this probably never happens
            log.warning("pinging scheduler failed to terminate");
            scheduler.shutdownNow();  // probably won't help, but as a last ditch effort...
        }
        final var remaining = Set.copyOf(connectionPingPongPlayers.keySet());
        connectionPingPongPlayers.clear();
        return remaining;
    }

    /**
     * Calls {@link #stop(long, TimeUnit) stop}<code>({@value #DEFAULT_STOP_TIMEOUT_MILLIS},
     * MILLISECONDS)</code>.
     */
    public Set<Session> stop() {
        return stop(DEFAULT_STOP_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, MILLISECONDS);
    }

    static final long DEFAULT_STOP_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 500L;



    /** Plays ping-pong with a single associated {@link Session connection}. */
    static class PingPongPlayer implements MessageHandler.Whole<PongMessage> {

        final Session connection;
        final Async connector;
        final int failureLimit;
        final long timeoutNanos;
        final boolean synchronizeSending;
        final BiConsumer<Session, Long> rttObserver;
        final MessageDigest hashFunction;
        final ByteBuffer hashInputBuffer;
        final ByteBuffer pingDataBuffer;

        int failureCount = 0;
        long pingSequence = 0L;
        long lastMatchingPongReceived = 0L;



        /** For both modes: negative {@code failureLimit} means {@code keep-alive-only}. */
        PingPongPlayer(
            Session connection,
            long timeoutNanos,
            int failureLimit,
            boolean synchronizeSending,
            BiConsumer<Session, Long> rttObserver,
            String hashFunction
        ) {
            this.connection = connection;
            this.connector = connection.getAsyncRemote();
            this.timeoutNanos = timeoutNanos;
            this.failureLimit = failureLimit;
            this.synchronizeSending = synchronizeSending;
            this.rttObserver = rttObserver;
            try {
                this.hashFunction = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashFunction);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException neverHappens) { // verified by the service constructor
                throw new RuntimeException(neverHappens);
            }
            hashInputBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES * 2 + Integer.BYTES);
            pingDataBuffer =
                    ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES * 2 + this.hashFunction.getDigestLength());
            connection.addMessageHandler(PongMessage.class, this);
        }



        /**
         * Sends a ping containing its "signed" sequence number and timestamp.
         * In case of {@code expect-timely-pongs} mode, if the previous ping timed-out, then
         * increments {@link #failureCount} and if it exceeds {@link #failureLimit}, then closes the
         * connection.
         * <p>
         * Called by {@link #scheduler}'s worker {@code  Thread}s.</p>
         * <p>
         * The exact structure of a ping data:</p>
         * <pre>{@code
         * pingSequenceBytes + pingTimestampBytes + hashFunction(
         *         this.identityHashCodeBytes + pingSequenceBytes + pingTimestampBytes)}</pre>
         * <p>
         * ({@code +} denotes a byte sequence concatenation)</p>
         */
        synchronized void sendPing() {
            if (failureLimit >= 0 && pingSequence > lastMatchingPongReceived) {
                // expect-timely-pongs mode && the previous ping timed-out
                failureCount++;
                if (failureCount > failureLimit) {
                    closeFailedConnection("too many timed-out pongs");
                    return;
                }
            }

            pingSequence++;
            hashInputBuffer.putInt(this.hashCode());  // using the default identity hashCode()
            hashInputBuffer.putLong(pingSequence);
            pingDataBuffer.putLong(pingSequence);
            final var pingTimestampNanos = System.nanoTime();
            hashInputBuffer.putLong(pingTimestampNanos);
            pingDataBuffer.putLong(pingTimestampNanos);
            pingDataBuffer.put(hashFunction.digest(hashInputBuffer.array()));
            pingDataBuffer.rewind();
            try {
                if (synchronizeSending) {
                    synchronized (connection) {
                        connector.sendPing(pingDataBuffer);
                    }
                } else {
                    connector.sendPing(pingDataBuffer);
                }
                // prepare for the next ping:
                hashInputBuffer.rewind();
                pingDataBuffer.rewind();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // on most container implementations the connection is PROBABLY already closed, but
                // just in case:
                closeFailedConnection("failed to send ping");
            }
        }



        private void closeFailedConnection(String reason) {
            if (log.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
                log.fine("failure on connection " + connection.getId() + ": " + reason);
            }
            try {
                connection.close(new CloseReason(CloseCodes.PROTOCOL_ERROR, reason));
            } catch (IOException ignored) {}  // this MUST mean the connection is already closed...
        }



        /**
         * If {@code pong} matches some previously sent ping, then does all the bookkeeping and
         * reports RTT if requested.
         * Ignores unsolicited {@code pong}s.
         * <p>
         * Called by a container {@code Thread}.</p>
         */
        @Override
        public void onMessage(PongMessage pong) {
            final var pongTimestampNanos = System.nanoTime();
            Long rttToReport = null;
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    final var pongData = pong.getApplicationData();
                    final var pongNumber = pongData.getLong();
                    final var timestampFromPong = pongData.getLong();
                    if (hasValidHash(pongData, pongNumber, timestampFromPong)) {  // matching pong
                        if (failureLimit >= 0 && pongNumber != lastMatchingPongReceived + 1L) {
                            // As websocket connection is over a reliable transport (TCP or HTTP/3),
                            // nonconsecutive pongs are a symptom of a faulty implementation
                            closeFailedConnection("nonconsecutive pong");
                            return;
                        }

                        lastMatchingPongReceived++;
                        final var rttNanos = pongTimestampNanos - timestampFromPong;
                        if (rttNanos <= timeoutNanos) failureCount = 0;
                        if (rttObserver != null) rttToReport = rttNanos;//report out of synchronized
                    }  // else: unsolicited pong
                } catch (BufferUnderflowException ignored) {}  // unsolicited pong with small data
            }
            if (rttToReport != null) rttObserver.accept(connection, rttToReport);
        }

        boolean hasValidHash(ByteBuffer bufferToVerify, long pongNumber, long timestampFromPong) {
            hashInputBuffer.putInt(this.hashCode());
            hashInputBuffer.putLong(pongNumber);
            hashInputBuffer.putLong(timestampFromPong);
            hashInputBuffer.rewind();
            return bufferToVerify.equals(ByteBuffer.wrap(
                    hashFunction.digest(hashInputBuffer.array())));
        }



        /**
         * Removes itself from {@link #connection}'s message handlers.
         * Called by the enclosing service for {@link Session connections} that still remain open
         * after {@link #stop()}.
         */
        void deregister() {
            try {
                connection.removeMessageHandler(this);
            } catch (RuntimeException ignored) {
                // connection was closed in the mean time and some container implementations
                // throw a RuntimeException in case of any operation on a closed connection
            }
        }
    }



    /**
     * Returns {@link Executors#newScheduledThreadPool(int)
     * Executors.newScheduledThreadPool}({@link Runtime#availableProcessors() availableProcessors}).
     */
    public static ScheduledExecutorService newDefaultScheduler() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    }



    static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(WebsocketPingerService.class.getName());
}
```